# Dynamically set zoom level based on a bounding box

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet map whose size depends on the size of the browser window. I would like the zoom level to be dynamically chosen so that it is as zoomed in as possible while showing the entirety of the bounding box.

Right now, I just have the zoom level hardcoded and the center point based on an average of points.

```
map = new L.Map('map', {
  center: new L.LatLng(
    latitudeSum/locations.length,
    longitudeSum/locations.length
  )
  zoom: 9
})
```

Instead, I'd like to give it a bounding box (two islands) and have the zoom level chosen based on the size of the window.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using [@Farhat's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76131/115), I figured out that all I needed was to pass an array of arrays:

```
map.fitBounds([
  [-4.8587000, 39.8772333],
  [-6.4917667, 39.0945000]
])
```

Comment: This is obviously missing a right square bracket near the end. Not sure why you reverted my edit.

Comment: You're right about the bracket - thanks. I'll fix that. Your edit also had an extra comma though.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas Code actually tested with trailing comma, too. (Because life is too short to bother with lines that pointlessly significantly differ in format.)

Answer (score 33):

You could simply use:

```
var group = new L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2, marker3]);

map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

Comment: Useful answer - that is a better way for centering and zooming - before I was just centering with a manual calculation. FitBounds was the answer I need, but I figured out you could simply pass into two coordinates to fitBounds and be done.

Comment: Definitely use the next answer unless you already have markers created.

Answer (score 0):

`map.fitBounds()` also works great if you're working with Google Map Polylines:

```
<!-- required for Leaflet Polyline support -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded/68e78190/Polyline.encoded.js"
crossorigin=""></script>
```

---

```
// polylines require backslashes to be escaped (Jinja example)
let encodedRoute = '{{ activity.strava_data['map']['polyline']|replace("\\", "\\\\")|safe }}';
let coordinates = L.Polyline.fromEncoded(encodedRoute).getLatLngs();
let map = L.map('map').fitBounds(coordinates);
```

Comment: Why was this answer down-voted?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it thanks to @Mike McKay! ;)

Note that I've added a couple of extra to the coords as a inner Padding, so the markers aren't right in the side of the map. This way looks beautifuler.

```
const [ ...coordinates ] = locations.map(marker => [ marker.coordinates.latitude + 
0.055, marker.coordinates.longitude + 0.055 ])

map.fitBounds([ ...coordinates ])
```

**VUE.JS WAY:**

```
mounted () {
   this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.initialZoom()
   })
}


methods: {
   initialZoom () {
       const map = this.$refs.myMap.mapObject
       const [ ...coordinates ] = this.locations.map(marker => [                                  
                                          marker.coordinates.latitude + 0.055,
                                          marker.coordinates.longitude + 0.055 
                                   ]) 

map.fitBounds([ ...coordinates ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank these contributors.  I just did this:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([<?php echo "$alat, $alon" ?>],8);


mymap.fitBounds([ @@ echo "[$maxlat, $maxlon],[$minlat, $minlon]"; @@ ]);
```

... and it works like a charm.  The @@ chars are the php brackets which  stackexchange removes) Many thanks!  I tried all kinds of computational schemes but did not know about fitBounds.  I'll be ripping out a lot of superfluous code.